# How to extract words starting with letters from A to L from a text in Python?

Tags: python, sorting, for-loop

**Language: Python**

So I extracted named entities from a text without using external libraries. Then I wanted to create two lists, one for the names starting with A-L; the other for the names starting with M-Z. I wrote this code, but it did not return any output. Anyone sees what's wrong here? Note that I am a beginner in  coding in general and might not be familiar with the terminology.

```
AL = []
MZ = []
for match in matches:
    if ((match[0] >= "A") and (match[0] <= "L")):
        AL.append(match)
        print("Words between A-L are:  ", AL)
    elif ((match[0] >= "M" and match[0] <= "Z")):
        MZ.append(match)
        print("Words between M-Z are: ", MZ)
```

edit:

I was asked what the "matches" came from:

```
pattern = re.compile(r'\.?\s\b[A-Z][a-z]\w+')
matches = pattern.findall(text) 


# print(matches)
```

And here is the output list in which I am trying to sort the names between A-L and M-Z:

```
matches = ['Rossini', 'William Tell', 'America', 'Athabaskan', 'Mackenzie River', 'Morse', 'Trappist', 'Plains', 'India']
```

And what I meant with "It does not work" is that it returns empty brackets.

```
Names between A and L:  []
Names between M and Z:  []
```

Thank you all for your contributions.

Comment: what is matches, what is the input, what is the expected vs. the actual output, where do you show the output? Have you used a debugger? E.g. what value does `match` have, what is `match[0]`, ....

Comment: works for me though

Comment: Yes, I should have clarified that part. I extracted name entities from a text without using NLTK or Spacy. Matches come from:

pattern = re.compile(r'\.?\s\b[A-Z][a-z]\w+')
matches = pattern.findall(text)

Comment: It's incredibly hard to helpfully answer a question like the one you asked. That's why @luk2302 posted their comment. Please edit your question to make it easier to answer. I suggest reading: [mre] and [What Do You Mean "It Doesn't Work"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147616/what-do-you-mean-it-doesnt-work).

Comment: In particular, can you fill `matches` with words, yourself, explicitly in the code, to reproduce your issue? I mean, add a line `matches = ["Al", "Bob", "Todd", "Zack", "todd", "zack"]` or something similar, at the beginning of the code in your question; then also tell us what output you got, and what output you would have expected instead.

Comment: To edit your question, please use the small [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70419854/edit) link at the bottom of your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So look at the following example:

```
def filter_words(words):
    AL = []
    MZ = []
    unclassified = []
    for word in words:
        if ((word[0] >= "A") and (word[0] <= "L")):
            AL.append(word)
        elif ((word[0] >= "M" and word[0] <= "Z")):
            MZ.append(word)
        else:
            unclassified.append(word)
    return AL, MZ, unclassified
    

AL, MZ, unclassified = filter_words(["Al", "Bob", "Todd", "Zack", "todd", "zack"])

print(AL)
print(MZ)
print(unclassified)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
['Al', 'Bob']
['Todd', 'Zack']
['todd', 'zack']
```

Depending on your requirements, you may want to call `word.upper()` before processing the if statements given that - as you can see - if a name starts with a lower case will be *unclassified*

Answer (score 0):

Here you have to take care of the word case:

```
matches = ['Arbre', 'Amie', 'Maison', 'Ligne', 'Zebre', 'Maths']

AL = []
MZ = []
for match in matches:
    match = match.upper()
    if ((match[0] >= "A") and (match[0] <= "L")):
        AL.append(match)
    elif ((match[0] >= "M" and match[0] <= "Z")):
        MZ.append(match)
        
print("Words between A-L are:  ", AL)
print("Words between M-Z are: ", MZ)
```

output is:

```
Words between A-L are:   ['ARBRE', 'AMIE', 'LIGNE']
Words between M-Z are:  ['MAISON', 'ZEBRE', 'MATHS']
```